# Apache Ignite fail to serialise lambda from remote node

Tags: lambda, ignite

I have this wired error when I use the cache query scan from a client node

```
        List<Account> data = accounts.query(new ScanQuery<UUID, Account>()).getAll().stream().map(uuidAccountEntry -> uuidAccountEntry.getValue()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

but if I try to return just the objects (not the Entry) with the filter I get an exception

```
        List<Account> data = accounts.query(new ScanQuery<UUID, Account>(), Cache.Entry::getValue).getAll();
```

NOTE* running in docker

> ignite_1     | 09:54:05.663 [query-#58] ERROR o.a.i.i.b.BinaryContext
>   - Failed to deserialize object [typeName=java.lang.invoke.SerializedLambda] ignite_1     |
>   org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Failed to read field
>   [name=capturingClass] ignite_1     |  at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.read(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:192)
>   ignite_1     |    at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.read(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:875)
>   ignite_1     |    at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize0(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1764)
>   ignite_1     |    at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryReaderExImpl.deserialize(BinaryReaderExImpl.java:1716)
>   ignite_1     |    at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.GridBinaryMarshaller.deserialize(GridBinaryMarshaller.java:313)
>   ignite_1     |    at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryMarshaller.unmarshal0(BinaryMarshaller.java:102)
>   ignite_1     |    at
>   org.apache.ignite.marshaller.AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.unmarshal(AbstractNodeNameAwareMarshaller.java:82)
>   ignite_1     |    at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.util.IgniteUtils.unmarshal(IgniteUtils.java:10140)
>   ignite_1     |    at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.query.GridCacheQueryRequest.finishUnmarshal(GridCacheQueryRequest.java:344)
>   ignite_1     |    at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.unmarshall(GridCacheIoManager.java:1530)
>   ignite_1     |    at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onMessage0(GridCacheIoManager.java:576)
>   ignite_1     |    at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:380)
>   ignite_1     |    at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.handleMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:306)
>   ignite_1     |    at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.access$100(GridCacheIoManager.java:101)
>   ignite_1     |    at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager$1.onMessage(GridCacheIoManager.java:295)
>   ignite_1     |    at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.invokeListener(GridIoManager.java:1569)
>   ignite_1     |    at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.processRegularMessage0(GridIoManager.java:1197)
>   ignite_1     |    at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager.access$4200(GridIoManager.java:127)
>   ignite_1     |    at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.communication.GridIoManager$9.run(GridIoManager.java:1093)
>   ignite_1     |    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   ignite_1     |    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   ignite_1     |    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

All other queries and put/get/... work perfect and no issues with serializing the Account object.

I tried many cache configurations but none seemed to make a difference.

Anyone had this issue or know how to resolve this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might be a bug (probably a bug). Try using a `private static class` instead of lambda for now. This is a general advice for Ignite anyway - lambda serialization is weird, especially in a distributed environment, so it's best to avoid it.

Comment: Thanks, @Stanislav This worked!.. but only after I created a public class in my shared model jar. see my answer.

Comment: Actually... Does it work if you just change the method reference to a lambda? I mean change `Cache.Entry::getValue` to `e -> e.getValue()`?

Comment: Also, what's your Java version?

Comment: no, I tried that too. Java version: 1.8.0_191, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.191.b12-11.fc29.x86_64/jre

Comment: And what's the Ignite version?

Comment: latest 2.7. I use zookeeper as cluster manager and this only happens on a cluster when a client calls a remote node. Can you replicate?

Comment: Tried this, but I can't reproduce it. I only run into issues with deserialization when I forget to restart the remote node. Can you try again making sure that you restart both nodes when you change the code of the lambda? Or perhaps share a reproducer project as a github repo (+ steps to run)

Comment: Yes, it is all running in docker so I run all docker containers same time after fresh build. have a look here -> https://github.com/effectus-io/effectus-ignite/tree/develop

Comment: There is a lot of files there. What should I look at? Can you create a script/JUnit/etc to run and see the problem?

Comment: Yes, it is my full project. Need for two ignite servers, one as a server and one as a client and run the scan query against the server from the client. There is no simple way to test this I think. by the way, I came across the same issue with the ScanQuery IgniteBiPredicate and solved it with the same shared predicate class....

Comment: Well, I'm OK with trying to run the full project, I just need the steps. Is it `docker-compose up`? And then what? Where should I look for the errors?

Comment: I pushed a new branch with the fault. Do you know how to use GraphQL browser? after you do a build run the docker compose and go to localhost:3000/browser and load the tasks query. I will add integration tests near future. tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments from @ Stanislav Lukyanov I changed my code and added a new class that implement the IgniteClosure and available on all nodes as part of my shared model jar.

```
import javax.cache.Cache;
import java.util.UUID;

public class AccountValueClosure implements IgniteClosure<Cache.Entry<UUID, Account>, Account> {
    @Override
    public Account apply(Cache.Entry<UUID, Account> e) {
        return e.getValue();
    }
}
```

Now I can call the cache query as expected with the closure instance...

```
        List<Account> data = accounts.query(new ScanQuery<UUID, Account>(), new AccountValueClosure()).getAll();
```

this ia ugly but works.

any feedback is welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I read in [mailing list](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com/ScanQuery-Transform-fail-to-deserialze-ignite-2-8-0-java-11-td33185.html) it was a bug [IGNITE-13212](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-13212) in `ScanQuery` (fixed in `v2.9`) that prevented from using lambdas or anonymous classes in query.

Recommendation from Ignite team:

> My advice is to avoid using lambdas and anonymous classes due to this specificity. Instead, you can create "private static classes" and Ignite will be serializing an instance of that class only:
>
> private static class MyFilter implements IgniteClosure {
> ....
> }
>
> Lamdas are nice for demos and simple code samples where Inner/OuterClasses are simple Java classes. While in real production environments, things can get messy.

If it does not help then you will have to make sure that your filter/code is deployed to all cluster nodes. Or you can try to upgrade to newer version and check if it works there.